# joomla 2.5 how fetch "Module Class Suffix"

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5

I am trying to fetch the Module Class Suffix of my menu module. This is how i am trying to achieve this: echo $module->$params->get('class_sfx'); But no results.. anyone know how to do this?
Also when I

print_r($module->params);
The result is

```
{"menutype":"test","startLevel":"1","endLevel":"0","showAllChildren":"0","tag_id":"","class_sfx":"cc_page_main_body_bottom_menu_item_panel_menu_container_first","window_open":"","layout":"_:center-top","moduleclass_sfx":"cc_page_main_body_bottom_menu_item_panel_website","cache":"1","cache_time":"900","cachemode":"itemid"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have too many $ in your echo. It should be $module->params->get('class_sfx'); watch the $ in from of params.

Within the module itself, you can typically just grab the parameters of that module using $params->get('class_sfx') without the $module piece.

Comment: You are right, just $params->get('class_sfx') works and I just realized $params->get('moduleclass_sfx'), thanx

Comment: Is it possible to change the suffix with an external php code for a module block in joomla ?

Comment: @user3408380 I'd recommend asking that question on joomla.stackexchange.com, because you're going to need to add more context. Change it always or just in a certain case? Why are you changing it in external code?

Comment: We have an code that make's warnings. no warning is green background color of the module and warning should be red background color of the module. We tought it was the best way to do this with suffix...

Comment: @user3408380 might be. It's not relevant to this question though, so please ask your own.